# How to get last 3 characters from a string using regex

Tags: regex, character

how to get last 3 or 5 digits from this given one using regex

4c113866bc43e2be48bbf85be829d7bc

Comment: When you say 'digits' do you mean just the numbers or the last three characters, whatever they are?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend

Comment: sorry last 3 or 5 characters,not digits..,sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $ anchor to mark the end of the string:

```
.{3,5}$
```

3 above is the min number of characters to match; 5 is max.